# Update only for non-blanks in KDB

Tags: kdb

I have a query `tab` with column `date` with format `yyyy.mm.dd`. I want to convert these dates into the format `yyyy-mm-dd` and I can do it successfully below:

```
q) tab:update date:{"0"^"-"sv'flip 4 -2 -2$'string`year`mm`dd$\:x}date from tab
```

However, some values in my column are blank and I will get `0000-00-00` for these values. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57167110/5305519) I understand I probably can just replace them with blanks, but it does not seem to be very efficient:

```
date[; "0000-00-00"; ""]
```

I was wondering if someone can point me in the right direction to update the whole column only for non-blank values? I am guessing it is something along the lines of `[date not like ""]` but I just can't get it to work with my `update` statement as a single command. Thank you.

Comment: Just for the record, the explanation of what ```q) tab:update date:{"0"^"-"sv'flip 4 -2 -2$\'string\`year\`mm\`dd$\:x}date from tab``` is doing is given by [this wonderful answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50696005/5305519)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
q)update date:{"-" sv "." vs string x}'[date] from tab
date
------------
"2020-07-16"
""
"2020-07-15"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can circumvent this issue altogether by changing the way you parse the dates:

```
q)t:([]date:`date$(10?100),0N)
q)t
date
----------
2000.01.20
2000.01.18
2000.03.28
2000.03.23
2000.02.15
2000.02.10
2000.02.02
2000.02.07
2000.01.26
2000.02.08

q)update ssr[;".";"-"]each string date from t
date
------------
"2000-01-20"
"2000-01-18"
"2000-03-28"
"2000-03-23"
"2000-02-15"
"2000-02-10"
"2000-02-02"
"2000-02-07"
"2000-01-26"
"2000-02-08"
""
```

This uses the [ssr](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/ss/#ssr) function on each date to simply replace each `"."` with a `"-"`.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your original question, the reason why an update statement with a where clause isn't working is because your original column is of type date. The update statement would only convert a subset of this column to type string, resulting in a mixed list, which is not compatible with the column of type date. To avoid this, while still using your original code, you can use a conditional vector update (https://code.kx.com/q/ref/vector-conditional/)

```
q)tab:([]date:(3?.z.d),2#0Nd)
q)parseDate:{"0"^"-"sv'flip 4 -2 -2$'string`year`mm`dd$\:x}
q)update date:parseDate date from tab where not null date
'type
q)update date:?[not null date;parseDate date;count[i]#enlist""]from tab
date
------------
"2006-06-02"
"2017-05-31"
"2006-09-28"
""
""
```

The other solutions provided achieve the same goal and in a much more direct manner, so I would recommend using one of those.